# Replace a portion of a vector with another vector

Tags: c++

I have a vector  of size 20 and a second of size 5. I wish to replace elements 11-15 in the
first vector with the second vector. I can do this by deleting those elements from the first 
vector and inserting the second vector. Is there another way to do this, perhaps by using assign?

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy

std::copy(src.begin(), src.end(), dst.begin()+10);
```

where `src` is the size 5 vector, and `dst` is the size 20 vector.

Comment: @RichardJohnson I just noticed I had misread your question, so I had the copying the wrong way around. I have fixed that.

Comment: Yeah, but it was close enough to figure out the rest.

Comment: I'm just wondering, shouldn't the copied to elements be freed first?

Comment: @user3655463 it depends on what you mean, because you definitely don't `free()` vector elements.

Comment: @user3655463 `std::copy` uses the assignment operator, there's no resource that needs free-ing